# building my first navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation

OK! I just started HTML and CSS today and thought it would be a good approach to learn by building something rather than just reading some text.

[ http://jsfiddle.net/GUkrK/ ]

So I decided to build one sample navigation bar.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> navigation bar </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="menu1">
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <span>GOOGLE</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu2">
            <a href="http://www.github.com">
                <span>GITHUB</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu3">
            <a href="http://www.quora.com">
                <span>QUORA</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu4">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                <span>FACEBOOK</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
color:red;
}

#menu {
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    height:108px;
}

#menu li {
    display:inline;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0px;
}

#menu a:link {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#27A285;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-color:#E1C618;
    color:brown;
}

hr {
    height:5px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

But now my problem is the positioning of that horizontal line. Do I have to place that by setting the pixels in absolute or relative positioning? Can't it be done automatically?
And how come the horizontal line does not cover the total width of the browser? and Can I adjust the width of that horizontal line?

**EDIT:** *Thanks everyone. Here is the edited sample http://jsfiddle.net/sunu0000/zdDU5/*

Comment: Pasted a viewable sample at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y8AAH/

Comment: i created a jsfiddle for you and others at http://jsfiddle.net/GUkrK/

Comment: thank you guys :)..i will use jsfiddle.net from now on when ever i ask

Comment: @unussunu remove the spaces between the attributes and the values, it might ruin your webpage in certain browsers. I also suggest using tabs. Also: are you new to webdevelopment? Did you seriously use http//: instead of http://?

Comment: @thew u mean the spaces between id and = and "menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from the CSS definition of `#menu`.

#### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8AAH/3/

#### CSS for #menu

```
#menu {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    height:108px; /* Looks better with like: 40px !! */ 
}
```

Depending on what your layout should look like this definition may be sufficient:

```
#menu {
    display:block;
    height:108px; /* Looks better with like: 40px !! */ 
}
```

**Updated sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y8AAH/4/

### Updated sample with centered menu

```
#menu {
    height:40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y8AAH/5/

Comment: vertical-align and display are useless too.

Comment: Right, I just copy and pasted it. - I guess another width and text-algin:center; was intended originally to position the menu centered on the screen?

Comment: width is useless too anyway ^^

Comment: @ smamatti yes initially i was trying to get it to the middle..with float i could push it to the right but failed to bring it to the middle. with display:block i was trying to increase the font weight before i knew that there is a property called font weight

Comment: Use `text-align:center;` for this. This works because your elements are displayed inline: `display: inline-block;` - See the updated sample at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: thats nice..btw what display:block does actually?

Comment: Block elements create a new line the the textflow and can have a greater margin to the previous and following elements. -- They are positioned **below each other** -- Block elements can contain text, inline- and other elements. _Please read a css reference for more information_

Answer (score 0):

I sugger you read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html) before continuing. It appears you don't really know what you're doing, so learn before asking question =p

Comment: I prefer the learning-by-doing method. You might start with some tutorial, _selfhtml_ or whatever you find, but you don't need to read at the properties etc. at the beginning. -- IMO this is not a real answer to this issue, but an advice which you could paste as comment.

Comment: I could agree with you if nobody thought "I see what I want so my code is good". Sadly..!

Comment: i actually saw some screen casts from thenewboston today and then i got started and about that w3.org page..stuff like that just kill my interest and unfortunately i dont have much patience :(